# Windows Form vs Unity3D HttpWebRequest Performance

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest, mjpeg

I am working on a simple program that grabs image from a remote IP camera. After days of research, I was able to extract **JPEG** images from **MJPEG** live stream with sample codes I got.

I did a prototype with using Windows Form. With Windows Form, I receive appropriately 80 images every 10 second from the IP camera.

Now I ported the code to **Unity3D** and I get about 2 frames every 10 seconds.

So basically about **78** Images are **not received**.
The thing looks like **medieval PowerPoint slide show**.

I am running the function in new Thread just like I did in the Windows Form. I first thought that the problem in Unity is because I was displaying the image, but it **wasn't**.

I removed the code that displays the Image as a texture and used an integer to count the number of images received. Still, I get about **2** to **4** images every **10 seconds**. Meaning in the **Windows Form** App, I get about **80** to **100** images every **10 seconds**.

Receiving **2** images in **10** seconds in **Unity** is **unacceptable** for what I am doing. The code I wrote doesn't seem to be the problem because it works great in **Windows Form**.

**Things I've Tried**:

1. I though the problem is from the Unity3D Editor run-time, so I called for Windows 10 64bit and ran it but that didn't solve the problem.
2. Changed the **Scripting Backend** from **Mono2x** to **IL2CPP** but the problem still remains.
3. Changed the **Api compatibility Level** from **.NET 2.0** to **.NET 2.0 Subset** and nothing changed.

Below is a simple function I that is having that problem. It runs too **slow** on Unity even though I called it from another **thread**.

```
bool keepRunning = true;
    private void Decode_MJPEG_Images(string streamTestURL = null)
    {
        keepRunning = true;
        streamTestURL = "http://64.122.208.241:8000/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240"; //For Testing purposes only

        // create HTTP request
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(streamTestURL);
        // get response
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

        System.IO.Stream imagestream = resp.GetResponseStream();

        const int BufferSize = 5000000;
        byte[] imagebuffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        int a = 2;
        int framecounter = 0;
        int startreading = 0;
        byte[] start_checker = new byte[2];
        byte[] end_checker = new byte[2];

        while (keepRunning)
        {
            start_checker[1] = (byte)imagestream.ReadByte();
            end_checker[1] = start_checker[1];

            //This if statement searches for the JPEG header, and performs the relevant operations
            if (start_checker[0] == 0xff && start_checker[1] == 0xd8)// && Reset ==0)
            {
                Array.Clear(imagebuffer, 0, imagebuffer.Length);
                //Rebuild jpeg header into imagebuffer
                imagebuffer[0] = 0xff;
                imagebuffer[1] = 0xd8;
                a = 2;
                framecounter++;
                startreading = 1;
            }

            //This if statement searches for the JPEG footer, and performs the relevant operations
            if (end_checker[0] == 0xff && end_checker[1] == 0xd9)
            {
                startreading = 0;
                //Write final part of JPEG header into imagebuffer
                imagebuffer[a] = start_checker[1];
                System.IO.MemoryStream jpegstream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imagebuffer);

                Debug.Log("Received Full Image");
                Debug.Log(framecounter.ToString());


                //Display Image
            }

            //This if statement fills the imagebuffer, if the relevant flags are set
            if (startreading == 1 && a < BufferSize)
            {
                imagebuffer[a] = start_checker[1];
                a++;
            }

            //Catches error condition where a = buffer size - this should not happen in normal operation
            if (a == BufferSize)
            {
                a = 2;
                startreading = 0;
            }

            start_checker[0] = start_checker[1];
            end_checker[0] = end_checker[1];

        }


        resp.Close();
    }
```

Now I am blaming **HttpWebRequest** for this problem. Maybe it was poorly implemented in Unity.  Not sure....

What's going on? Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: "medieval PowerPoint slide show."  heh  :)

Comment: I removed it because it makes the code more complicated since you can't use Texture2D from another thread so I the code I have that can do that is long to post here. It is not required to solve this problem but thanks for trying. I used the Debug.Log() to display the number of frames received.

Comment: Also marc_s removed the medieval  powerpoint statement. I am not happy at all.

Comment: no what I mean is, it's excellent that you tried *removing the display code* -- because you demonstrated THAT is not the bottleneck; that is not causing the problem

Comment: if you're suffering questions-from-newbs burnout, @programmer   ... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318401/294884  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it perhaps the case that one has to use `Read[a lot]` instead of `Read` ??

`Read[a lot]`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx

> Return Value Type: System.Int32 The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be *less than the number of bytes requested* if that many bytes are not currently available

Conceivably, `ReadAsync` could help, [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx), although it results in wildly different code.

Comment: I really don't care if solution is in another thread or here. As long long it is not something I've tried, I am willing to it. I am trying your solution and will get back to you. Using Read[a lot] will require re-writing almost the whole code but I am doing that now. Maybe that would work or maybe not.

Comment: I'm afraid I simply do not know .....right the thread aspect is irrelevant. But it's possible Read[a lot] will be quicker: maybe that's the secret. But maybe it is unrelated.  Yes it's a huge change.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am trying Read[] it.

Comment: I slept and returned back to programming again this morning and finished re-writing that. It was a little bit complicated. The speed of the code I have now is > the one that works on Windows Form. I get about 100 frames from Unity now while Windows Form gives me 89 frames max. I am filing for a  Bug report on Unity Website but I know they won't fix it. Just filing the report so that other people with the problem will see it and not pull their hair out while trying to make their code work. It is simply a bug.  I've been trying to solve this for 5 days. Thank you so much.

Comment: I AM SO HAPPY DUDE!  TBC if you use the `Read[a lot]` pardigm, it works OK as a workaround?  Or did you have to go to `ReadAsync`.  Fill us in!   YOU ROCK

Comment: Yes, it worked. I used imagestream.Read(imagebuffer, 0, BufferSize) then loop through it with many logic....I decided I am not going to use ReadSync for this because this is an image processing program and everything needs to be fast. I believe that using ReadSync will require call back functions which will take more time. Any millisecond taken away from this will make the images arrive slowly. It takes time to call a function even though the time is un-noticeable. Using Read will block but using thread with it will solve that problem.

Comment: I don't know if I am right about the ReadAsync stuff but It looks like it would be slow. I was gonna give up but your answer saved me. Although, I had to re-write all the code. Is it a good thing to wrap the network and stream code around with the word *using*? I read that it is a good thing to do but I don't know why...

Comment: got it, `Read[a lot]` is the way to go!  forget about the "using" thing for now.  Unity will keep it clean for you. it's not going to be a problem at first.  (If you ever do want to get rid of it "yourself", very simply use Dispose .. the whole "using" thing is crapola) If you worry, whatever overall GameObject this is sitting on: Just Instantiate one and use it for your video, then get rid of it.  Simply Instantiate a new one when you want to use your system. Again Unity will look after it for you, it's not a big worry. Even if  it leaks it will run 1000s of times until you have a problem :)

Comment: I definitely siggest a new separate question regarding "how to dispose / if necessary" if you want to get in to that issue - it's a big dealio!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit puzzled as to what part of your code you are saying has the performance problem - its it displaying the MPG or is it the snippet of code you've published here ? Assuming the HttpRequest isn't your problem (which you can easily test in Fiddler to see how long the call and fetch actually take) then I'm guessing your problem is in the display of the MPG not the code you've posted (which wont be different between WinForms and Unity)

My guess is, if the problem is in Unity you are passing the created MemoryStream to unity to create a graphics resource ? Your code looks like it reads the stream and when it hits the end-of-image character it creates a new MemoryStream which contains the entire data buffer content. This may be a problem for Unity that isn't a problem in WinForms - the memory stream seems to contain the whole buffer you created, but this is bigger than the actual content you read - does Unity perhaps see this as a corrupted Jpg ?

Try using the MemoryStream constructor that takes an byte range from your byte[] and pass through just the data you know make up your image stream.

Other issues in the code might be (but unlikely to be performance related); Large Object Heap fragmentation from the creation and discard of the large byte[]; non dynamic storage of the incoming stream (fixed destination buffer size); no checking of incoming stream size, or end-of-stream indicators (if the response stream does not contain the whole image stream, there doesnt seem to be a strategy to deal with it).

Comment: **"HttpRequest problem ... which you can easily test in Fiddler"** That's a very astute idea.  @Programmer, you can use fiddle to actually test if that part is the woe.

Comment: "it displaying the MPG or is it the snippet of code you've published here"  PhillipH, he already said he tried *not* displaying it, and that did not help the problem.  (If I read OPs post correctly.)

Comment: I don't think he read the whole question. I also mentioned that I don't care about displaying the image now. I am just using integer+Debug.Log() to show how many images received. Also, He said I  should try using the MemoryStream with that takes a constructor of byte array which what I did in the code I posted above. MemoryStream is not the problem because I comment it before posting my question. Even with it commented, the problem was still there.  The Fiddler thing he mentioned sounds promising but I will tryot when I finish writing the Stream.Read (Byte[], Int32, Int32) code.

Comment: agreed.  indeed the Fiddler thing sounds like a sensible unit test.