# Streaming live footage from camera to Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, video-streaming

Let's say I have a wireless camera that I want to stream footage from to unity in real-time. Is there a way to achieve this?

Bonus questions:

- What about cameras with wider angles (180, perhaps even 360)
- How much of an issue would the delay be if this is a footage I want to be interacting with
- Possible to send more data such as depth perception(using depth perception camera) aside from the regular footage only?
- Am I crazy or has this been done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume this is a camera with Ethernet port or Wi-Fi that you can connect to and stream images from it live.

If so, then yes, it can be done with Unity.

*How it is done without an external library*:

**Connecting to the Camera**:

**1**.Connect to the-same local network with the camera or if unpn is supported, you can also connect to it through internet. Usually, you need the IP and the port of the camera to do this. Let's say that the Camera IP Address is `192.168.1.5` and the port number is `900`. The url to connect to is `http://192.168.1.5:900`.

Sometimes, it is simply an url that ends with **.mjpg** or **.bin** such as `http://192.168.1.5/mjpg/video.mjpg` and `http://192.168.1.5/mjpg/video.bin`

Every camera is different. The only way to find the url is to read its manual. If the manual is not available, connect to it with its official Application then use Wireshark to discover the url of the camera Image. The `username` and the `password`(if required) can also be found in the manual. If not available, google the model number and everything you need should be found.

**Extracting the JPEG from the Camera**:

When connected to the camera, the camera will be sending endless data to you. This data you can scan and retrieve the image from it.

**2**.Search for the JPEG header which is `0xFF` followed by `0xD8`.  If these two bytes are next to each other then start reading the bytes and continue to save them to an array. You can use an index(`int`) variable to keep count of how many bytes you have received.

```
int counter = 0;
byte[] completeImageByte = new byte[500000];
byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[500000];
receivedBytes[counter] = byteFromCamera;
counter++;
```

**3**.While reading the data from the camera, check if the next two bytes is the JPEG footer which is `0xFF` followed by `0xD9`. If this is true then you have received the complete image(1 frame).

Your image bytes should look something like:

`0xFF` `0xD8` someotherbytes(thousands of them)..... then `0xFF` `0xD9`

Copy `receivedBytes` to the `completeImageByte` variable so that it can be used to display the image later on. Reset `counter` variable to 0.

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(receivedBytes, 0, completeImageByte, 0, counter);
counter = 0;
```

**Displaying the JPEG Image to the Screen**:

**4**.Display the Image to screen

Since you will be receiving many images per second, the most [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36044940/3785314) way I found to display this is to use `RawImage` Component. So, don't use `Image` or `Sprite Renderer` for this if you want this to run on mobile devices.

```
public RawImage screenDisplay;
if(updateFrame){
Texture2D camTexture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
camTexture.LoadImage(completeImageByte);
screenDisplay.texture = camTexture;
}
```

You only need to do `camTexture = new Texture2D(2, 2);` once in the `Start()` function.

**5**.Jump back to step **2** and continue doing it until you want to quite.

**API for connecting to the Camera:**.

Use [`HttpWebRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35829285/3785314) if the camera requires authentication (username and password).

For those that does not require authentication, use [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html). When using `UnityWebRequest`, you must derive your own classes from [`DownloadHandlerScript`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerScript.html) or your app will crash as you will be receiving data non stop.

Example of deriving your own class from `DownloadHandlerScript`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class CustomWebRequest : DownloadHandlerScript
{    
    // Standard scripted download handler - will allocate memory on each ReceiveData callback
    public CustomWebRequest()
        : base()
    {
    }

    // Pre-allocated scripted download handler
    // Will reuse the supplied byte array to deliver data.
    // Eliminates memory allocation.
    public CustomWebRequest(byte[] buffer)
        : base(buffer)
    {
    }

    // Required by DownloadHandler base class. Called when you address the 'bytes' property.
    protected override byte[] GetData() { return null; }

    // Called once per frame when data has been received from the network.
    protected override bool ReceiveData(byte[] byteFromCamera, int dataLength)
    {
        if (byteFromCamera == null || byteFromCamera.Length < 1)
        {
            //Debug.Log("CustomWebRequest :: ReceiveData - received a null/empty buffer");
            return false;
        }

        //Search of JPEG Image here

        return true;
    }

    // Called when all data has been received from the server and delivered via ReceiveData
    protected override void CompleteContent()
    {
        //Debug.Log("CustomWebRequest :: CompleteContent - DOWNLOAD COMPLETE!");
    }

    // Called when a Content-Length header is received from the server.
    protected override void ReceiveContentLength(int contentLength)
    {
        //Debug.Log(string.Format("CustomWebRequest :: ReceiveContentLength - length {0}", contentLength));
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{

    CustomWebRequest camImage;
    UnityWebRequest webRequest;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[90000];

    void Start()
    {
        string url = "http://camUrl/mjpg/video.mjpg";
        webRequest = new UnityWebRequest(url);
        webRequest.downloadHandler = new CustomWebRequest(bytes);
        webRequest.Send();
    }
}
```

You can them perform step **2**,**3**,**4** and **5** in the `ReceiveData` function from the `CustomWebRequest` script.

**Controlling Camera**:

Cameras have commands to pan, rotate, flip, mirror and perform other function.This is different in every camera but it is simple as making GET/POST request to a url of the camera and providing the queries. These commands can be found in the camera manual.

For example: `http://192.168.1.5?pan=50&rotate=90`

**Other Frameworks**:

[AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/video.html) - A free framework that can handle both [JPEG/MJPES](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/dbf7400d-fbe9-e770-57aa-f63bc507c917.htm) and [FFMPEG](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/ec7a1e39-3bbc-9ab0-629e-8829f5c94d05.htm) from the camera. You have to modify it to work with Unity and you should if you can't do step **2**,**3**,**4** and **5**.

Comment: To add to this answer if someone wants a quick solution: here's an example that will do this without any external libraries or dependencies. 
https://github.com/DanielArnett/SampleUnityMjpegViewer

Comment: @DanielArnett Check your link. I don't approve it because it requires "System.Drawing.dll". That should be avoided in Unity. It simply doesn't work on every platform.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'll look through your response when I have time and update that repository to remove the Drawing.dll dependency.